# Integrating S3ObjectManager in AppSync Initialization: For User Pools and Upload of S3Object attributes

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I included an instance of S3ObjectManager during AppSync initialization using the initialization below which makes use of User Pools for authorization. However this results in an error (discussed below):

```
func initializeAppSync() {
        do {
            // You can choose the directory in which AppSync stores its persistent cache databases
            let cacheConfiguration = try AWSAppSyncCacheConfiguration()

            // Initialize the AWS AppSync configuration
            let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(
                appSyncServiceConfig: AWSAppSyncServiceConfig(),
                userPoolsAuthProvider: {
                    class MyCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider : AWSCognitoUserPoolsAuthProviderAsync {
                        func getLatestAuthToken(_ callback: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
                            AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().getTokens { (tokens, error) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    callback(nil, error)
                                } else {
                                    callback(tokens?.idToken?.tokenString, nil)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return MyCognitoUserPoolsAuthProvider()}(),
                cacheConfiguration: cacheConfiguration,
s3ObjectManager: AWSS3TransferUtility.default()
            )

            // Initialize the AWS AppSync client
            appSyncClient = try AWSAppSyncClient(appSyncConfig: appSyncConfig)
        } catch {
            print("Error initializing appsync client. \(error)")
        }
    }
```

**ERROR:** Running the app while submitting non-s3 object attributes work well. But when I add an s3 object attribute for auto upload to S3, this error results:

```
Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=310 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=BackgroundUploadTask <E7DEB20A-6A56-4C57-B98D-EBF31A9FFD45>.<1>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "BackgroundUploadTask <E7DEB20A-6A56-4C57-B98D-EBF31A9FFD45>.<1>",
    "LocalUploadTask <E7DEB20A-6A56-4C57-B98D-EBF31A9FFD45>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2096}
```

**Background:**
Which AWS Services are you utilizing?

**Amplify** to scaffold the project: amplify init, amplify push, amplify add auth, amplify push, amplify add storage, amplify push

**Authenticated Role:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::flogfitstore-prod/public/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

**AppSync** to upload an image s3object attribute to S3 with graphql schema such as below:

```
type Post @model @key(fields: ["username", "createdAt"]) {
    username: String!
    createdAt: String!
    title: String
    content: String
    image: S3Object
    comments: [Comment] @connection (name: "PostComments", sortField: "createdAt")
}

type S3Object {
   bucket: String!
   key: String!
   region: String!
}
```

Provide code snippets (if applicable)

My code already successfully saves other non-s3object attributes in DynamoDB using AppSync. This implies that the code in AppDelegate, initializeAppSync() function above, that is called in didFinishLaunching, correctly initializes AppSync.

Here are the non-s3object attributes

```
let mutationInput =  CreatePostInput(username: myUsername, createdAt: String(Date().timeIntervalSince1970), title: "Title", content: content)
```

However, when I include the image attribute which is an s3object, the error results during upload:

```
let s3ObjectInput = S3ObjectInput(bucket: "flogfitstore-prod", key: "public/" + fileName, region: "ap-southeast-1", localUri: fileUrl.absoluteString, mimeType: "image/png")

let mutationInput =  CreatePostInput(username: myUsername, createdAt: String(Date().timeIntervalSince1970), title: "Title", content: content, image: s3ObjectInput)
```

This documentation suggests another way of initializing AppSync
https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/storage#usage-with-graphql-apis-complex-objects

```
let appSyncConfig = try AWSAppSyncClientConfiguration(url: AppSyncEndpointURL,
                                                      serviceRegion: AppSyncRegion,
                                                      credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider,
                                                      databaseURL:databaseURL,
                                                      s3ObjectManager: AWSS3TransferUtility.default())
```

But this results in an error because this seems to be not in harmony with the use of Cognito User Pools.

So the way to go is the initialization as in the above initializeAppSync() and include configuring s3ObjectManager.

Please help.

Environment(please complete the following information):

Pod File:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyFitSpo' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.10.3'
  pod 'AWSAppSync', '~> 2.14.1'
  pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.10.3'
  pod 'SVProgressHUD'
  pod 'FSPagerView'
  pod 'CTSlidingUpPanel'
  pod 'AWSS3', '~> 2.10.3'   # For file transfers

end
```

Dependency Manager: Cocoapods
Swift Version : 5
Device Information:

Device: Simulator
iOS Version: 12.4